# PyQt5 QWebEngineView window won't show

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview, qwebenginepage

I wrote a simple test program to load a URL in a QWebEngineView. The program works on Mac; the browser pops up and I can see the webpage. But on Windows 7, the browser window never appears after I call show():

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

class Browser(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.load(QUrl('https://google.com'))
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.pageReady)

    def pageReady(self, success):
        if success:
            self.show()
        else:
            print('page failed to load')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    browser = Browser()
    app.exec_()
```

Is there something I'm missing? My firewall is disabled, so it shouldn't be a connection problem...

Comment: try add `self.resize(640, 480)` before `self.show()`

Comment: and add `browser.loadProgress.connect(print)` to see the progress

Comment: I see 100 being printed out, so it loads apparently. But the window never appears, even if I resize it before showing it.

Comment: it seems to be a bug, what version of Qt Webengine and PyQt5 do you have? How did you install it?

Comment: PyQt5 (5.12.1);
PyQt5-sip (4.19.15);
PyQtWebEngine (5.12.1).

Installed via:
pip install PyQt5,
pip install PyQtWebEngine.
I did not install Qt separately.

Comment: Try installing PyQt5 to PyQtWebEngine 5.12: `pip install PyQtWebEngine==5.12 PyQt5==5.12`

Comment: On the other hand, try another pc with windows, historically Qt WebEngine has had problems with old windows drivers, maybe this is the cause. If the problem persists, I recommend reporting it.

Comment: 5.12 has the same problem. I'll try another computer.

Comment: Try the following code https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/d6dcd227fbafbc03138b6c73b8dbe224